# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with using dispatch_async

Tags: concurrency, objective-c++, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I'm attempting to execute a block via an asynchronous dispatch queue in Objective-C++.  Here's a class fragment of what I'm trying to do...

```
class Blah {
public:
    void dispatch(const EventPtr& event) {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(_queueName.c_str(), NULL);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            this->dispatchEventToSubscribers(event); 
        });
        dispatch_release(queue);
    }
protected:
    Dude _dude;
    void dispatchEventToSubscribers(const EventPtr& event) {
        _dude.dispatchToSubscribers(event);
    }
}
```

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS within the dispatchEventToSubscribers method.  When I check to see what the value of `_dude` is, XCode tells me it is out of scope.  I can only assume that I'm losing `this` somehow.  Checking the concurrency docs:

> For blocks that you plan to perform
>   asynchronously using a dispatch queue,
>   it is safe to capture scalar variables
>   from the parent function or method and
>   use them in the block. However, you
>   should not try to capture large
>   structures or other pointer-based
>   variables that are allocated and
>   deleted by the calling context. By the
>   time your block is executed, the
>   memory referenced by that pointer may
>   be gone. Of course, it is safe to
>   allocate memory (or an object)
>   yourself and explicitly hand off
>   ownership of that memory to the block.

So how do I dispatch asynchronously a method on `this` object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, making a local instance of `event` worked...I'm not sure why...i.e...

```
void dispatch(const EventPtr& event) {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(_queueName.c_str(), NULL);
    EventPtr eventPtr = event;  //local instance...
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        this->dispatchEventToSubscribers(eventPtr); 
    });
    dispatch_release(queue);
}
```

Comment: It's because the original event goes out of scope, this was undefined behaviour. On the other hand, if you make a copy, the block will also make a copy of it. (in theory it *could* make a copy of the reference, but it was not made that way)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no problems. Make sure the Blah instance is alive when the block executes. Blocks automatically retains Objective-C instances. not for C++ instances.